# Laravel Jetstream inertia ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (on fresh installation)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, inertiajs

I have created a new Laravel jetstream project with inertia.
I use Vagrant Homestead.
When I open a new page I get this error: `GET http://localhost:3000/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

Also Vue devtools won't load, I get this error: `DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://schoolsysteem.test/js/index.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net: :ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE`.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the problem by just disable the browser-sync feature. Remove these 2 lines from app.blade.php:

```
@env ('local')
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js"></script>
@endenv
```

You can fix the problem with Vue.js Devtools by installing the beta (Vue 3) extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg